# Are postgres connection able to manage multiple requests at the same time?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, connectivity

I have an application using node Postgres driver to connect to my Postgres 12.

The pool size is currently 1.

Is it possible, **for one connection**, to have multiple requests sent before receiving the responses?

Figure two requests:

- request A will last 10 seconds to be processed by the database,
- request B will last 1 second.

If this is possible, that request B will be answered before request A?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can only have a single statement executing at the same time on a PostgreSQL connections.

PostgreSQL v14 introduces [pipelining of SQL statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/libpq-pipeline-mode.html), but that still means that one statement will execute after the other. Besides, I doubt that Npgsql already has support for that.

Use several database connections.